# Bug with images and markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, images

Test this in a new question/answer:

```
![*google!*][1]

  [1]: http://www.google.com.ar/images/nav_logo6.png
```

You will see that it fails because it will parse the * as italics. It should be ignored within links and images.

Trying it now:

![*google!*][1]

```
  [1]: http://www.google.com.ar/images/nav_logo6.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't technically a markdown problem. The [HTML sanitizer](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html) is getting it.

It ends up [like this](http://is.gd/5Igup):

```
<p>
<img src="http://www.google.com.ar/images/nav_logo6.png" 
     alt="<em>google!</em>" />
</p>
```

The sanitizer kills the whole thing because of embedded tags. Which I agree with. Well, I wrote the code, so I'm biased, but you know what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

Just escape the first star.

```
![\*google!*][1]

  [1]: https://www.google.com.ar/images/nav_logo6.png
```

[image: *google!*]

Comment: Didn't think of *that*!

Comment: Should this be added to the `faq`?

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with including images generated by one of the many LaTeX servers.  For these, the alt text should be the exact LaTeX code used to produce the image: it makes it accessible to those who use screen readers to read the alt text, and it makes it possible to simply cut-and-paste the formula without having to go through and undo all the Markdown escaping.  Given how often the underscore is used in LaTeX formulae, it would be extremely useful to have this fixed in the markdown implementation used.

This has been fixed in the PHP markdown port (even the version without all the extras) and, I believe, in the maruku ruby variant.