# Angle brackets in image alt texts should be auto-encoded

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, markdown, images

For example if I try to link like this:

```
![image][1]
```

It looks like this:
[image]

**But** if I try this:

```
![image>you][3]
```

It ends up jumbled:
[image: the way it will look]

### Ha!

It seems as I have broken the html.

This should be fixed if people want to be able to have `>` in their alt tags

---

Other fun with the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug):

```
![image><h1>how is this possible?</h1><a href="#">Weird</a>, don'tcha think?<a ][4]
```

Becomes:
[image: second error]

Comment: since you also tagged this "support": The workaround is `&gt;`

Comment: @balpha haha true true. but the issue with `>` is still present :-)

Comment: @balpha see update. an issue with any direction you put those brackets. you can put full html in there!

Comment: How is that different? That's the same thing. The HTML sanitizer eats everything between opening and closing angle brackets that doesn't look valid. And an img tag that ends in the middle of the alt attrbute certainly doesn't :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=fc6f51bb5914de4dd0f99ca58538274ac8b8c081

http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/detail?r=f5a5cebbe3ea71c7453032eeb63ccab034d1e3d5

Both changes are in the next build.