# Image markdown breaks if the alt text contains a URL

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, images

Including a URL in the alt text for an image breaks it, as long as the URL is preceded by a space:

#### Normal image

```
![Alt text](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png)
```

[image]

#### Broken image

```
![ http://meta.stackoverflow.com](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png)
```

http://meta.stackoverflow.com">

Comment: More specifically, it happens in cases where the URL has a space before it. The auto-linker doesn't know better and tries to throw a `<a>` in there, which upsets the sanitizer...this is kind of in the same thread as a number of other escape-related issues, hrm.

Comment: @TimStone Ah, that makes more sense. I couldn't find a duplicate, but I didn't know exactly what the problem was; there might be one

Comment: I don't remember this specific issue coming up before, so I think you're good. Just trying to think of there's a good way to resolve all these issues at once, without (as balpha mentioned the other day) special-casing them all.

Comment: @tim if this issue hasn't come up before, I think the relevant question is *do we care?* I like to default to *no*.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I'm inclined to care about cases like this because it's non-obvious what happens, so it's not immediately apparent to people that they just shouldn't do that. Admittedly the usecase here seems pretty limited (Michael, why were you trying to put a URL in the title attribute?), but if it's possible to address this along with the other auto-linker versus sanitzer issues then I figure "Why not?"

Comment: Does this issue backtrack to markdown proper?

Comment: @TimStone I was editing a post that left "enter description here", and the image was a screenshot of text that included a URL, so I tried to put the text in

Comment: Ah, makes sense.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: By that logic, no bug would ever be fixed. Ever.

Comment: @tom no, I'm saying if it has come up once in ~4 years it's not a very significant issue. And that's true.

Comment: @Jeff: No, it's not significant, but defaulting to "we don't care" isn't a great way to push forward a programming project, IMO!

Comment: @tom I unapologetically default to "we don't care" for *issues that have come up once in four years*.

Comment: @Jeff: Actually isn't it just a specific symptom of a more general bug, one that's come up a fair amount? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110470/markdown-image-alt-text-is-not-escaped-resulting-in-the-image-not-being-display)

Comment: @tom nope, it's the "why does the alt text for an image *need* to be a URL?" problem, which is unique as far as I know. Certainly in the four years I've worked on this project I've seen it come up hardly at all. Remember that alt text will NOT be clickable, it'll be plain text, so wanting a formal URL in there is.. bizarre at best. So I'll be reverting to my regularly scheduled "don't care" mode on this one.

Comment: @jcolebrand It doesn't track back to the original Markdown implementation because the auto-linker is a custom deviation.

Comment: @Jeff: I tend to cycle on the side of "why should it not be an URL? if the image is of an URL, then the alt text should be able to be an URL". Then again, I don't have to program it.

Comment: Hey everybody! I don't want `<a href="url">title</a>` in my onhover thanks! Let's just fix it so that the message stays and maybe show: `url title` or just `title`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you indicated in comments you're trying to preserve the URL that's in the image, I suggest:

`alt="www.foo.com"`

Rather than

`alt="http://www.foo.com"`

Since the plain text alt for the image won't be clickable anyway, the `http://` is irrelevant.

Comment: Indeed. And for users of screen readers I *assume* it is a bit nicer to have the URL read out aloud without the *h-t-t-p-colon-slash-slash* part. (If a URL is useful to start with then?)

Comment: Also, if the URL is relevant enough to include in the alt text, it should probably be presented elsewhere in the post anyway.